# $\mathbb{Q}$-Zariski Closure not equal to smallest Q-subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, hodge-structure

I wonder if there is a simple instance of the following phenomena : an abstract subgroup S $\subset GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ whose $\mathbb{Q}$-Zariski closure isn't a group ?

Is there some criteria to ensure this is not happening ? (Maybe under some reductivity hypothesis, e.g. Mumford-Tate groups ?)

(there is a non intuitive example in exercice 11 of [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~chai/620_00/hw1.pdf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Echai/620_00/hw1.pdf)).

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Take some elements $A_1,\dots, A_n$ that generate a dense subset $\Gamma$ of a non-abelian connected reductive group $G \subseteq GL_n$.

For instance, I can take $$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, A_2 = 
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ which generate $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ which is Zariski dense in $G = SL_2$.

Now take a parametric curve $A(t)$ in $G$ which passes through $A_1, \dots ,A_n$. For example, I can take $$ A(t) =\begin{pmatrix} t & 1 \\ t^2-1 & t \end{pmatrix}$$ which gives $A_1$ for $t=1$ and $A_2$ for $t=0$.

Now just take the group generated by $A(\pi)$, or use your favorite transcendental number.

Let $T$ be the torus generated by $A(\pi)$, which is defined over $\pi$, and defines a point in the space $G/ N(T)$ of toruses in $G$ conjugate to $T$. The $\mathbb Q$-Zariski closure of this point in $G/N(T)$ is a one-dimensional curve, since the point is defined over $\mathbb Q(\pi)$, which has transcendence degree $1$. If we take the inverse image of this curve in the universal family of tori and project to $G$, we get a $\dim T +1$-dimensional subset of $G$, defined over $\mathbb Q$, containing all powers of $A(\pi)$, and therefore the $\mathbb Q$-Zariski closure of the subgroup generated by $A(\pi)$ has dimension $\leq \dim T+1$ and can't contain all of $G$.

But by construction, the minimal $\mathbb Q$-subgroup containing $A(\pi)$ contains $A_1,\dots, A_n$ and thus is $G$.

For example, in the $SL_2$ case, the Zariski closure consists of matrices whose two diagonal entries are equal, a set which is closed under taking powers, but not products.

Because this works for any non-abelian connected reductive group, there is no reasonable condition on the Mumford-Tate group that rules it out, although $G = \mathbb G_m^n$ is OK because all its Zariski closed subgroups are defined over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not sure about what you call $g$ at the end of your middle paragraph ?

Comment: @Szariski Understandably - I meant $\dim T$.